# Dynamic table names in snowflake with FLYWAY

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-migration, flyway

I want to have 1 migration scripts in flyway, where I will have a `create table` statement. I would like to have `dynamically` name of the table with the use of placeholders, which will create as many tables as the number of prefixes I define.

How my migration looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ${prefix}_table(
    id int
)
```

and then in bash I execute:

```
prefixes=(PREFIX_1 PREFIX_2)
for prefix in "${prefixes[@]}"
do
    flyway migrate -placeholders.prefix="$prefix"
done
```

Unfortunately only 1st table with `PREFIX_1` is created for 2nd loop iteration I have information that:

*Current version of schema `TEST`: 1
Schema `TEST` is up to date. No migration necessary. *